# One point differential $>0$ implies monotone?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, $f'(x_0)>0, x_0\in (a,b)$. Can we find a neigbourhood of $x_0$ where $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample let $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x+2x^2\sin(\frac1x)$ for $x\ne0$. Then $f'(0)=1$ but $f$ is not monotonic in any neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f \in C^1(a,b)$, that is, $f$ has continous derivative, then we can always find a neighborhood of $x_0$ on which $f$ is increasing. This is a consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem. If $f$ does not have continuous derivative then this fails. For instance, take

$$
  g(x) =
  \begin{cases}
  x + 2x^2\sin(1/x), &x \neq 0 \\
  0, & x = 0.
  \end{cases}
$$